# Swift generate error for default return value

Tags: swift, switch-statement, swift2

The following code sample pretty well illustrates what I'm after. I have a function that is expected to return a given type. It does that based on an *incomplete* switch. But in the event the `default` case is reached, I was hoping to just generate an error. Rather than return an `optional` which someone chooses to `!` and then die at that point.

```
func someFunc(value:UInt8) -> SomeType {
    switch value {
    case 0x00:
        return SomeType.foo()
    case 0x13:
        return SomeType.bar()
    default:
        break // BUT I WANT AN ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `fatalError()` if you want to completely stop execution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the program to *terminate* in the default case
(because the default case would indicate a *programming error*), 
use `fatalError()`:

```
func someFunc(value:UInt8) -> SomeType {
    switch value {
    case 0x00:
        return SomeType.foo()
    case 0x13:
        return SomeType.bar()
    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected value \(value)")
    }
}
```

`fatalError()` causes the program to terminate immediately
with a error message like

```
  fatal error: Unexpected value 99: file main.swift, line 13
```

The `fatalError()` function is marked with `@noreturn` (resp. with 
the return type `Never` in Swift 3),
so the compiler won't complain on missing cases or missing
return values.

In contrast to similar function like `assert()` or `assertionFailure()`,
`fatalError()` is never "optimized away", it is evaluated in debug, optimized and unchecked builds.

Answer (score 1):

```
func someFunc(value:UInt8) -> (SomeType?,NSError?) {
switch value {
case 0x00:
    return (SomeType.foo(),nil)
case 0x13:
    return (SomeType.bar(),nil)
default:
    return (nil,NSError("Something wrong")
}
```

}

This is how I would implement the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct SomeType {
    static func foo() -> SomeType {
        print("foo")
        return SomeType()
    }
    static func bar() -> SomeType {
        print("bar")
        return SomeType()
    }
}

struct E: ErrorType {}

func someFunc(value:UInt8) throws -> SomeType {
    switch value {
    case 0x00:
        return SomeType.foo()
    case 0x13:
        return SomeType.bar()
    default:
        throw E()
    }
}

do {
    try someFunc(100)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
// prints
// error
```